# RoR Spree Asset Differs on Production & Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, jquery-plugins, assets, spree

I'm tryin to solve this for nearly 2 days. I'm pretty mad at now.

I'm using Spree (latest version) with Rails 5. I'm trying to use W3's Shape template as theme. Css is ok and working fine but I can't manage to get workin javascript assets.

Here is my vendor/javascripts/spree/frontend/all.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require accounting.min
//= require shape/all ---> As you can see i require my template's assets

//= require_tree .
//= require spree/frontend/spree_auth
//= require spree/frontend/spree_i18n
```

And here is the assets/javascripts/shape/all.js

```
//= require_tree .
```

And inside that Shape folder, there are javascript assets.

When in development mode, everything works perfect. There is no issue. But when i try to switch production mode or deploy to heroku, template's javascript assets does not included.

Thank you all.

Edit: For a temporary solution, I did include my problematic js assets by old classic html way. But still I'm really curios about how can this happen.

Comment: if(public asset folder is not empty)
{copy your public assets folder to different location on your local machine.
Switch the public assets folder in your app with an empty folder}

then precompile assets locally `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` push on git master branch and then try deploying on to heroku. Let's see if that works

Comment: @SumeetMasih Thanks for reply but I did try that. Actually I did try multiple things in order the get this thing work. Precompiling is just one of them.

Comment: did you do `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile=false`   in`config/production.rb`

Comment: Yes I did try that but no luck. I just give up. I think for small projects, spree comes with big overhead.